# Count with Having didn't return anything

Tags: mysql

I'm curious about how to write the correct query when I wanna use count function with having clause..
So I have a table named : seat
and here are the columns:

```
SEAT

ID_SEAT      ID_TIME      STATUS
-----------------------------------------
  A1      |      1    |  Available
  A2      |      2    |  Available
  A3      |      1    |  Available
  A4      |      1    |  Reserved
```

And so on.
I have 119 rows which the status is 'Available' and 1 row which the status is 'Reserved'.

And here is the query in MySQL:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) AS number FROM seat
WHERE ID_SEAT = 'A3' AND ID_TIME = '1'
HAVING COUNT(status) IN (SELECT COUNT(status) from SEAT where status = 'Available')
```

But the query didn't show anything..Any help and clear answer would be very helpful ..thank you :)

EDIT :

What I really want to display is something like this :

```
STATUS        NUMBER
---------------------
Available      119
```

The STATUS field above is for a certain ID_SEAT...in my case the ID_SEAT = 'A3' and for ID_TIME = 1

EDITTTTT :

thank you for all the answer to me..
Now I can fix it clearly..

So I'm using "UNION" to separate the query..I'm using 2 queries to make it works..

here the code :

```
SELECT status from seat where ID_SEAT = 'A3' AND ID_TIME = '1' UNION 
SELECT COUNT(status) from seat
where status = 'Available'
```

however the code above is work for mysql query.. thank you a lot :)

Comment: so you're basically saying HAVING 1 IN (119)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want your result like the one you showed.

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) as number
FROM seat
WHERE status = 'Available'
GROUP BY status
```

If you wanted to see status of seat then simply select status, no need for count

```
SELECT status
FROM seat
WHERE ID_SEAT = 'A3' AND ID_TIME = '1'
```

If you must, return status of seat and a count of ALL available seats

```
SELECT status,(SELECT count(*) FROM seat WHERE status = 'Available') as number
FROM seat
WHERE ID_SEAT = 'A3' AND ID_TIME = '1'
```

Comment: yeah but remember that STATUS field that I want to show is for ID_SEAT = 'A3', So I can't reduce the "WHERE" clause for the certain ID_SEAT and ID_TIME

Comment: You can't. Either you get the status of ID_SEAT = 'A3' or you count all available seats. Not both at the same time. Well you can but it's not reccomended. just do 2 separate queries. One to only grab the status of ID_SEAT = 'A3' and another query to grab a count of all available seats.

Comment: If you must select status of ID_SEAT = 'A3' and a count of all avilalbe seats in one query, use the last query of my answer.

Comment: You should test by setting the status of ID_SEAT='A3' to 'Reserved' and then see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use an aggregate function like count, sum, avg etc... in the select part of the query, as well as a non aggregate function--"status" in this case--you MUST have a "group by" clause.

So it would look like this:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status), AS number FROM seat
HAVING COUNT(status) IN (SELECT COUNT(status) FROM SEAT WHERE status = 'Available')
GROUP BY status
```

This will make it so you see two rows.  One for available with a count of 119, and one for reserved with a count of 1.

Comment: I place the Group By line after the Where clause line..but it didn't work to :(

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't test and I wasn't thinking :) Take out the ID_SEAT out of the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, the expression `(SELECT COUNT(status) from SEAT where status = 'Available')` is going to return 119.  However, you are only selecting one row, so the two values can never be equal.

I think you want:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) AS number
FROM seat
GROUP BY status;
```

This will return all status.  If you really only want `'Available'`, then filter using a `where`:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) AS number
FROM seat
WHERE status = 'Available';
```

EDIT:  (Based on clarification in comment)

Oh, if you only want the status information for `seat` number 23, you can get that with a `having` clause:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(status) AS number
FROM seat
GROUP BY status
HAVING sum(id_seat = '23A') > 0;
```

The `having` clause is counting up the number of rows, for each status, where the `id_seat` has a value of `23`.  You want the `status` where there is at least one row, which is what the `having` clause does.

Comment: yeah but remember that STATUS field that I want to show is for ID_SEAT = 'A3', So I can't reduce the "WHERE" clause for the certain ID_SEAT and ID_TIME

Comment: @Aprilia . . . That really clarifies the question.  See the edited version.

Comment: whoaaa!!! it works!but i wanna ask you..what is '23' for? But it really works..can you explain the line of this `HAVING sum(seat = 23) > 0;`? thank you

Comment: i am confused, how can that work? there is no column called `seat`.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/387c1/2/0